# Node Server Configuration Tests

Tags: node.js, chai

Is there a way to restart a server with different configurations for different test files using Chai? I've tried stopping and starting in the `before` and `after` tags but it doesn't seem to restart.

Code below:

```
let server;
.
.
.
before((done) => {
      process.env.SOME_FLAG = "true";
      server  = require('../app/server');
}
after((done)=>{
    server.server.close();
    done();
});
```

Comment: This does not appear to reload it the server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the downvotes but I'm guessing that you have a `NODE_ENV` variable that you pass and you would like to test an express-like server application via chai/mocha

This is what I use in my `before` & `after` methods:

```
let server = null;

before(done => {
  let app = application.create();
  server = app.listen(port);
  done();
});

after(done => {
  server.close();
});
```

Of course you would then need to run your requests against the listening server `http://localhost:[port]`. Also `application.create()` returns an app instance.

Comment: I'm new to Node.js but I did try doing something like that before in my above code. The only difference is I import the server file instead of calling `application.create()` Not sure how that works on an Express server.